# Can't access command line of Raspbian/Kodi on boot by pressing ESC

Tags: ssh, kodi, boot-issues

I can't get to the command line by hitting Esc on reboot when prompted. Kodi version from the settings screen is "Compiled: Feb 2 2015)".

I can't SSH in because my RPi isn't getting DHCP renewed on reboot (another thread...).

Here's the error when I hit Esc and the SSH login appears:

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 raspbmc tty2
raspbmc login: init: kodi pre-stop process (1121) terminated with status 143
init: kodi main process (379) killed by TERM signal
init: console-setup pre-start process (1152) terminated with status 1
rpcbind: rpcbind termianting on signal. Restart with "rpcbind -w"
```

It gives me the login prompt but then just keeps going. From there it just boots back into Kodi/Rasbmc.

No idea where to start here as I don't know how to access a darn thing without the command prompt. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to just boot Kodi and go to power > exit ? If I do this i instant boot to Raspbian. From there you can switch X windows with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (until F7, Xserver Raspbian). I'm guessing you're using OpenElec?

Comment: I have it setup so whenever Exit/Reboot is pressed from the Kodi frontend it reboots back into Kodi. But only a week ago I was able to Esc to the command line as expected. Yes, OpenElec.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with dhcp and ssh
Power off in mine Kodi succeded with black screen but 
CTRL + ALT + F2 or F3 let me switch to Terminal.without closing Kodi